# My button's work and I believe the function is working but the equals button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get this simple calculator to work with as few moving parts as possible. I thought I was calling everything correctly.

I have changed my function twice and I am using console.log to verify that the number buttons are working.

```
var num1 = '';
var num2 = '';
var operator = '';
var total = '';


 // set the initial value of the display to 0
 $('.calcDisplay').val(0);

 // console.log the value of a number button when it is clicked
 $('.number').on('click', function(event) {
 console.log('number', event.target.value);
  });

 $('.plus').on('click', function (event) {
  calculate('plus');
   console.log('plus', event.target.value);
 });
$('.minus').on('click', function (event){
 calculate('minus');
});
$('.multiply').on('click', function (event){
 calculate('multiply');
});
$('.divide').on('click', function (event){
 calculate('divide');
});

 function calculate(operator){
  if (('.convertForm').valid ()){
   var calculator = createCalculator();
   var result = calculator[operation]();
   var message = calcualtor.num1 + "" + operator + "" + 
 calculator.num2 + "is" + result;
   $('.result').text(message);
 }
```

I am expecting to get this function to calculate basic operations.

Comment: So what happens? Anything? Errors reported? What does `createCalculator()` do?  What sort of debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Can you paste a working snippet instead of just the JavaScript?

Comment: Seems to be a typo ? `calcualtor.num1`

Comment: I can click on the numbered buttons and they console log, but the operators are not logging. It appears I haven't written that code yet Pointy. Ghassen I don't know how to do that yet and I don't see where that snippet button would be. Yvo Thank you for helping me with the typo.